# iOS: Xcode: Architecture: armv7 vs armv6

Tags: ios, xcode, sharekit, armv7

I have a project that was created two years ago when iOS 2.0 was present.  The app it self has been getting successful updates along the way and doing fine. So far in Xcode, in Architecture settings, I had 'armv7 arm6' and my deployment was iOS 3.0.

Recently, I intergrated Facebook (ShareKit) in to the app, and it requires iOS 4.0 or higher and just 'arm7'.  When I change the settings to those and create the binary, Application Loader rejects the upload with following message:

```
iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6
```

If I change it back to 'armv7 arm6', then the app won't run because of the Facebook (ShareKit) requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/) can currently run on both architectures. (armv6 support has been added last week)

However recommended deployment target is 4.0, though using some tweaks you might get it compile with target set to iOS 3.0 or 3.1, one of these tweaks is described [here](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/pull/127)

If you decide to use [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/), make sure you follow [install instructions](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit) carefully. Since it has undergone a lot of changes recently, best bet might be to readd it from scratch.